# Rename XIB file without loosing outlet connection

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib

First, I've made the choice to not work with storyboards, as I'm quite used to working only with code (I'm from Java). So here is the behaviour I don't understand :

1/ I create a .xib file containing a view and, lets say a button.

2/ I create a ViewController (as i understood : one xib file containing many subviews is associated with one viewController)

3/ I set the file owner of my xib to the viewcontroller class

4/ I make the outlet connection between the button and the ViewController by the drag and drop "magic" of xcode.

Here everything works fine : at the beggining in my ViewDidLoad(), the outlet is set as a UIButton when i run the app, and i can use it

5/ I **rename** the xib file

6/ **The outlet is nil when i run the app at the begginning of ViewDidLoad()**. That is the problem.

I dont understand why. The file's owner of the xib is still the same, its still my viewcontroller.swift (i didnt rename the viewcontroller class but only the xib), so why this viewcontroller cant see what is his view by searching what xib it owns now ?? I tried to clean the project, close it, even restart my laptop nothing changed.. I may have missed something because its not normal that i cant rename a xib file without having to recreate another viewcontroller file ?

I'm definitely not used to work with graphical interface, and i was glad to see many developpers are not too. Can you advise me some tips to create a app without storyboards, using only xib like "HTML" files and everything else in the code ?

Thank you

Comment: If you're using a xib file, you're not doing it in code. A storyboard is just like multiple connected xib files (with the added benefit that you don't have to worry about File's Owner) - and nothing to do with HTML

Comment: thats another question but why i dont use storyboard is because i like to code as many low-level as possible. Also, if storyboards are connected views, why all my app wouldnt be one single storyboard ? what is the critera to say this view goes to this storyboard1 and this view in the SB2 ?

Comment: If you want to do it all in code, then _don't_ use xib files. If you want to use xib files, then you're _not_ doing it in code, so you should probably use storyboards.

Comment: How you split a storyboard is up to you, and depends on the use case. You can put your sign-up flow in one storyboard, your settings screens in another, etc. You could put all your views in one storyboard, or have one storyboard per view… it's up to you. Storyboard references can be used to provide "links" between storyboards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The custom class of the File's Owner placeholder in the xib has only one effect: it tells Interface Builder (the xib editor part of Xcode) what outlets and actions to offer on the File's Owner placeholder. The File's Owner's custom class does **not** affect how your view controller finds its nib file at runtime.

(A xib file is an XML-based document you edit in Interface Builder; a nib file is the compiled version of the xib file and is included in your app bundle.)

[The `UIViewController.nibName` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621487-nibname?language=objc) tells you what you need to know:

> This property contains the value specified at initialization time to the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method. The value of this property may be `nil`.
>
> If you use a nib file to store your view controller's view, it is recommended that you specify that nib file explicitly when initializing your view controller. However, if you do not specify a nib name, and do not override the `loadView` method in your custom subclass, the view controller searches for a nib file using other means. Specifically, it looks for a nib file with an appropriate name (without the `.nib` extension) and loads that nib file whenever its view is requested. Specifically, it looks (in order) for a nib file with one of the following names:
>
> 1. If the view controller class name ends with the word ‘Controller’, as in `MyViewController`, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the class name without the word ‘Controller’, as in `MyView.nib`.
> 2. It looks for a nib file whose name matches the name of the view controller class. For example, if the class name is `MyViewController`, it looks for a `MyViewController.nib` file.

So, if you have renamed your xib, and now the outlet is nil, then your view controller is probably **not loading the nib file at all**, because of one or more of these reasons:

1. You passed a nib name to the `UIViewController.init(nibName:bundle:)` initializer, and that nib name is incorrect.
2. You passed nil to the `UIViewController.init(nibName:bundle:)` initializer, and none of the naming rules described in the `nibName` documentation matches your renamed xib file name.

Here are some possible solutions:

1. Pass your renamed xib file name (without the `.xib` extension) to the `UIViewController.init(nibName:bundle:)` initializer.
2. Override the `nibName` property in your `UIViewController` subclass to return the renamed xib file name (without the `.xib` extension).
3. Rename the xib file to match one of the rules described in the `nibName` documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I didnt mentionned how i called the viewcontroller :
window?.rootViewController = IntroViewController() in AppDelegate.swift. This is to call the ViewController "Intro" at the beggining. When doing UIViewController.init(), how do swift "know" what viewcontroller to call ? I tried to put the param like this : IntroViewController(nibName:"IntroView") but no constructor was made that way.

Comment: (i found it :  IntroViewController.init(nibName : "IntroLayout", bundle:nil) )
Anyway thank you for having taken the time to answer :)

Comment: Thanks, it turns out it was necessary to rename the xib file )))